# How to pass name value annotation in Java method?

Tags: java, annotations

The annotation class Get.java

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Get {
    String value();
}
```

The annotation class Field.java

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Field {
  String value();
}
```

The interface class GetInterface.java

```
public interface GetInterface {
    @Get("/group/user?")
    void getUser(@Field("id") String id);
}
```

I want to use this GetInterface in the following, how can I get the annotation name so I can use that as the parameter attribute to construct a get url with query parameters

```
public class Request implements GetInterface {

  @Override
  public getUser(String id) {
    String getPath = "/group/user?"; //How can I get this path from the annotation?
    String name = "how can I get the name attribute 'id'????";
    String value = id; //this will be 123 in this example
    //with the name an value, I can then construct a url like this
    //https://www.foo.com/group/user?id=123
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    getUser("123);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

```
Method m = GetInterface.class.getMethod("getUser");
Get getAnnotation = m.getAnnotation(Get.class)
Field fieldAnnotation = m.getParameters()[0].getAnnotation(Field.class)
String path = getAnnotation.value();
String fieldName = fieldAnnotation.value();
```

Comment: `getAnnotation.value()` returns a single String, not an array.

Comment: I guess you are right! I did my code using another annotation as example... thanks! I fixed it